# Opening universal links doesn't open in app

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to implement the "Universal links" feature in my app. I'd like any link that starts with my domain to open in the app. e.g:

"www.mydomain.com/login" - Open in the app

"www.mydomain.com" - Open in the app

"www.mydomain.com/something/123" - Open in the app

I've followed a tutorial on this, but clicking on "www.mydomain.com" link in notes opens in safari. This is my apple-app-site-association under the .well-known folder (Take in note that I've taken out the team and identifier and package name):

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
       "appID": “12345ABCDE.my.package.name",
       "paths": [
        "*"
       ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In Signing & Capabillities under Associated Domains:

[image]

When I put in my domain in (this)[https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/] universal link validator these are the results I get:

[image]

But I'm not sure what it means when it says "Your file can't behind redirects"

Does anyone know why app links are still not working in my app?

Comment: That isn't a good validator; it seems old. It refers to signed files, which are no longer required. This is a better one. https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/  It reports that your json isn't valid.   The json in your question has the wrong opening double quote on the string for the app id. Is this the case in your actual file?

Comment: Yes it's the same in my actual file, so I've replaced it and I'm going to try it now. Thank you

Comment: Hi, it works now. The quote was part of the problem, but also that I forgot to put www infront of my domain. Thank you!